# QTextObjectInterface PySideでの導入方法について

Tags: python, python3, qt, pyside

**参考にしたサイト**
[(本家)レクトを描画できた例](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232882/nice-text-formatting-in-qtextedit-like-qt-creator-does)
[日本語での説明](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/mrbonze/comment?date=20110417#c)
**リファレンスの実行手順**
[PySide Documentation QTextObjectInterface](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTextObjectInterface.html)
の導入方法をまねしました。
1.まずTypeを決定。(UserObjectと同値かそれ以上)
2.`QTextCharFormat.setObjectType()`の引数に1をセット
3.`QTextObjectInterface`を導入
4.1で決定したタイプと同じタイプと、3のインスタンスを、
`QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.registerHandler()`
に登録。
5.`QChar.ObjectReplacementCharacter`(`PySide`では`u"\uFFFC"`を、上記`charFormat`で挿入。
　この`ReplacementCharacter`と衝突するたびに`drawObject`と`IntrinsicSize`が呼び出されると書いてありました。

**試作コード**

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent=None)
        try:
            self.textedit = TextEdit()  
            self.setGeometry(200,200,500,500)           
            self.setCentralWidget(self.textedit)
        except Exception as e:
            print(54,e)
class TextEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(TextEdit,self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.setParent(parent)
        try:
            self.example_charFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
            self.example_charFormat.setObjectType(QtGui.QTextFormat.UserObject+1)
            self.example_charFormat.setProperty(1,"どうすればいいんだ？")    
            self.fm = TextObjectInterface(self)
            self.document().documentLayout().registerHandler(self.example_charFormat.objectType(),self.fm)                     
        except Exception as e:
            print(106,e)
    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        try:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_At:                
                tc = self.textCursor()
                char = self.example_charFormat
                char.setBackground(QtCore.Qt.green)
                tc.insertText("\uFFFC",char)
                return
            return QtGui.QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self,event)
        except Exception as e:
            print(65,e)        
class TextObjectInterface(QtCore.QObject, QtGui.QTextObjectInterface):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(TextObjectInterface, self).__init__(parent=None)        
    def intrinsicSize(self,doc, posInDocument, charformat):  
        try:            
            print(43)
            tf = charformat
            s = str(charformat.property(1))       
            fn = tf.font()
            fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(fn)
            return fm.boundingRect(s).size()
        except Exception as e:
            print(33,e)                        
    def drawObject(self,painter,rect,doc,posInDocument,charformat):
        try:            
            print(47)
            s = str(charformat.property(1))
            painter.drawText(rect,s)
            painter.drawRect(rect)       
        except Exception as e:
            print(24,e)      
def main():
    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(65,e)    
    textediter = MainWindow()
    textediter.show()
    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

しかし、これではインターフェース自体呼び出されませんでした。
`PySide`で上記のコードが動く方法はあるのでしょうか？どこが間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: 上段のサンプル(Pyside向け)で、`intrinsicSize`と`drawObject`の`format`引数を`QtGui.QTextCharFormat`として扱おうとしていますが、誤記でしょうか? (PySideのページには`QtGui.QTextFormat`とあるので)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyside用のコード(上段)について、2点変更すると動作しないでしょうか?

1. 以下の箇所の「"\uFFFC"」を「u"\uFFFC"」に変更
   (python 2系ではunicode文字の記載は接頭句として「u」をつけると聞いたので)

   ```
   # 修正前
   tc.insertText("\uFFFC",char)
   # 修正後
   tc.insertText(u"\uFFFC",char)
   ```
2. `TextObjectInterface`の継承元クラスとして[`QPyTextObject`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QPyTextObject.html#qpytextobject)にする。
   (`QPyTextObject`の説明だと`QtCore.QObject`と`QtGui.QTextObjectInterface`を多重継承したクラスとあるので、内容は一緒に見えるのですが、これで試すと`registerHandler`が成功するようです)

   ```
   #変更前
   class TextObjectInterface(QtCore.QObject, QtGui.QTextObjectInterface):
   #変更後
   class TextObjectInterface(QtGui.QPyTextObject):
   ```