# Custom Text Objects PrintPreviewの表示について-Ruby表示コードとPreview表示コード掲載-

Tags: python, qt

PrintPreviewの導入に成功し、プリントのプレビュー表示を
　早速出してみました。
　プレビューを表示するためのコードです。
　読んでもらえたら結構勉強になるかもしれ
　ません。
　プレビューを表示するためにどうすればい
　いのか考えあぐねていたら、ここを読んでみて
　ピンと来た気がします。毎度長文で申し訳あり
　ません。
　[Print A Text Through A Printer Using PyQt4](http://Print%20A%20Text%20Through%20A%20Printer%20Using%20PyQt4)

```
　　　　 printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
        printer.setDocName(self.windowTitle())
        printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A4)        
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.NativeFormat)
        printer.setOrientation(QtGui.QPrinter.Portrait)
        printer.setResolution(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setCopyCount(self.printer_pagecountspinbox.value())
        #ここで、ドキュメントに設定してある余白を、プリンターにもセットしてしまうと、二重に計上されるバグ？そのため、コメント化を行って、回避。
#        printer.setPageMargins(self.main_menubar_layout_document_left_margin_spinbox.value(),self.main_menubar_layout_document_top_margin_spinbox.value(),\
#                                                self.main_menubar_layout_document_right_margin_spinbox.value(),self.main_menubar_layout_document_bottom_margin_spinbox.value(),\
#                                                QtGui.QPrinter.Millimeter)
        if self.main_view.textediter.document().documentLayout().pageCount() == 1:
            #なぜか、一ページ目の白紙ドキュメントは、サイズがQtCore.QSizeF(797,-1)となり、正常に1ページ目を表示してくれないため、再認識修正（コンストラクタで本当はやってるんだけど反映されない。ここは、B5やB4等を増やしたときに拡張する予定）
            self.main_view.textediter.document().setPageSize(QtCore.QSizeF(797,1123))
        self.print_preview_widget = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(printer,self) 
            #showMaximized()を使い、全体表示をすれば、何も映らなくなる。なぜかわからないバグ。            
        self.print_preview_widget.setGeometry(150,150,1500,1500)
            #ここがミソ。コールしない。コールすると打ち出しを始めてしまったりする　C++と表記が異なる点。QPrinter*　つまり、ポインタを渡せという事。純粋Pythonerには少しハードルが高かった。
            #今までもコールでprinterをセットしていたかもしれない。忘れたころにまたやってしまう失敗。
            #残念ながら、self.main_view.textediter.document().print_とした場合、Failed to connect signal　エラーが発生、これでもよくないかと考えてしまう。
        self.print_preview_widget.paintRequested.connect(self.main_view.textediter.print_)
        self.print_preview_widget.exec_()
```

**具体的な問題**  
　　既にページネーションが行われているので、ページ間の
　余白は意識することなくQTextEditの編集中の状態をその
　まま、プレビューに表示できるようになりました。
　もちろんプリントもできます。
　しかし、`QTextObjectInterface`によるカスタムオブジ
　ェクトが、正確に表示されません。
　`QTextObjectInterface`内のpainterメソッドは、下記の
　コードかこちらを参照
　[QTextObjectInterfaceの導入方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37162/qtextobjectinterface-pyside%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%8E%E5%85%A5%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
　ちょうどカスタムオブジェクトが描かれているべきところに、
　灰のつぶのような小さな点が見えたので、もしやと思い、拡
　大ボタンを押して、1500%くらいまで　拡大してみました。
　すると、豆粒から見ても豆粒のような、灰カスのような文字が、
　大きさはともかくとして、正確に表示されていました。
　**空白であるにせよ、そこに文字が入り込むだけのスペース

　が空いています。その空白の左はじに、灰粕のように、黒い粉

　がついています。painterのフォントサイズだけ1以下にされて

　しまったような外観です。**
　つまり、QTextEdit中には通常の表示がなされているはずのカス
　タム　オブジェクトが、プレビュー画面で表示したときは、どん
　なにFontをいじっても、蟻よりも小さくなっています。
　　もちろん、そのままプリントしても、その通りの文字でした。
　　さすがプレビューとは言えない状況でした。
　私のエディタは、Wordソフトのように、ページネーションが行わ
　れているので、`QTextDocument　or QTextEdit.print_()`を
  利用すれば、そのまま表示してくれます。
　　私は、あくまでもこの方法でプリントしたいと思っています。
　[便利なプリントメソッド～ページネーション時にはこれ。](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTextDocument.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTextDocument.print_)
　　カスタムオブジェクトを、プリント時に改めて挿入すればよい
  とも思いましたが、一応レンダリングはなされている以上、小さ
  な黒い点＋挿入文字で、正確な表記ではなくなります。また、上
  記のメソッドを使えば、painterでごちゃごちゃ書かなくてもい
  いので、非常に楽なのです。特に`TextBlock`がページ間でまた
　がった場合の処理が不要になるので、一番楽です。
　小さいながらも、文字が載っているということは、必ず、この文
  字を正常な状態で載せる方法もあると思っています。しかしその
  手がかりが今のところ全くつかめません。
　CustomTextObjectを作れる仕組みがありながら、セーブ&ロード、
  プリントの手段については、リファレンスに載っていないのは、案
  外簡単な方法があるんじゃないかと考えています。じゃないと作っ
  てもアプリを消せばすべておじゃんになるから、絵にかいた餅もい
  いところだと思うからです。
  そして、こちらが、自分なりのルビ表示機能のコードです。実際ま
  だルビは汚いです。

```
class RubyTextObjectInterface(QtGui.QPyTextObject):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(RubyTextObjectInterface, self).__init__(parent=None)        

    def intrinsicSize(self,doc, posInDocument, format):  
        try:                     
            #ここのformatはQTextFormat
            #ここに、docを引数として通すと、後の処理で原因不明のエラーが発生　format_tc = QtGui.QTextCursor(doc)は、エラーになる。
            findblock = doc.findBlock(posInDocument)
            format_tc = QtGui.QTextCursor(findblock)
            format_tc_charFormat = format_tc.charFormat()
            format_charFormat = format.toCharFormat()
            format_charFormat.setFont(format_tc_charFormat.font())
            rubysize = format.property(4)
            offset = format.property(5)            
            size = QtCore.QSize(len(format.property(1))*format_charFormat.font().pointSize()+(len(format.property(2))-1)*rubysize,format_charFormat.font().pointSize()+rubysize+offset+2)
            return size
        except Exception as e:
            print(33,e)                        
    def drawObject(self,painter,rect,doc,posInDocument,format):

        try:
            #そもそものviewportを取得してみた。結果は(0,0,796,1131)
#            print(102,painter.viewport())
#            painter.setViewport(int(doc.rootFrame().frameFormat().leftMargin()),int(doc.rootFrame().frameFormat().topMargin()),int(doc.pageSize().width()),int(doc.pageSize().height()*doc.documentLayout().pageCount()))
            #formatのプロパティに現在位置を登録し、常に更新
            format.setProperty(3,posInDocument)            
            rubysize = format.property(4)
            offset = format.property(5)
            #ドキュメント上のテキストカーソルを取得            
            format_tc = QtGui.QTextCursor(doc)
            #拡張書式のある場所へ移動
            format_tc.setPosition(posInDocument)
            #現在カーソルがある位置のcharFormat()を取得
            format_tc_charFormat = format_tc.charFormat()
            #formatをcharFormat化
            format_charFormat = format.toCharFormat()
            #ルビに現在のカーソル位置のフォントをセット
            format_charFormat.setFont(format_tc_charFormat.font())
            #rectは親文字のための位置情報なので、rubyはその上にレンダリングさせるように微調整
            ruby_rect = QtCore.QRectF(rect.x(),rect.y()-rubysize-offset,rect.width(),rubysize+offset)
            painter.setFont(format.property(7))
            painter.drawText(rect,format.property(1))
            painter.setFont(QtGui.QFont(format.property(8).rawName(),rubysize))
            painter.drawText(ruby_rect,format.property(6),format.property(2))
```

ご存知の方や、こうすればどうかというお考えをお持ちの方は
　何でもいいのでお寄せください。よろしくお願いします。
　**～蛇足～**
　**カスタムテキストオブジェクトに当たっての導入必要な処理**　進捗状況
　①BoldやItalic,Underlineをダイナミックに適用する。　　　　　　　 　×
　②fontの変更、fontsizeの変更をダイナミックに適用する。　　　　　　  ×
　③printoutとpreview表示を可能にする。                            ×
  ④save&loadを可能にする。（強引に可能にしたが、もっと楽な方法が欲しい）　△
　⑤copy&pasteを可能にする。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　×
　①と②と⑤は、脳内でちょっと図が出来上がっていて、④は、もっ
　と楽な方法が欲しいです。これはまたおいおい質問していけれ
　ばいいなと思っています。
　すぐに試してみる事も可能なのですが、インターフェースの
　メソッドを、IntrinsicSizeとdrawObject以外に追加しても
　怒られませんよね？

Comment: 再現コードがあると回答も得られやすくなると思いますが、再現コードを質問に追記することは可能でしょうか?

Comment: 全くその通りであると思います。しかし、どのコードを載せればよいかなと考えてしまいました。問題が発生しているような発生していないような、カスタム化したオブジェクトさえ使わなければ、全き正常なのです。そこで、二つの重要なコードを載せたいと思います。ルビ文字コードとプレビューコードです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

直接実行できるコードではないので、気づく範囲の回答になりますが、
少なくとも`QPrinter.setResolution()`の引数を間違えているように見えます。
このメソッドの引数は、具体的なDPIを指定することになっており、`QPrinter.HighResolution`は指定しません。`QPrinter.HighResolution`は`QPrinter`のコンストラクタで指定します。(参考: [QPrinterの文書](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QPrinter.html))
あるいは、プレビューであれば`QPrintPreviewDialog`のコンストラクタに`QPrinter`を指定しなくても十分と思います。

一方、`QPrinter.HighResolution`を`QPrinter`に指定する場合、1200DPIとして扱われるようなので、`RubyTextObjectInterface.intrinsicSize()`や`drawObject()`内で描画物を「1200 ÷ 96」倍で描画すると、プレビュー画面で見えるようになると思います。

＃「96」は`QPrinter.ScreenResolution`を指定した際のDPI。

以上、参考になれば幸いです。